# Javascript - hide/show - unsorted lists - onClick

Tags: onclick, html-lists, hide, visibility, show

I'm trying to hide/show unsorted lists by an onClick-Event.

At the top are three different Options to select:

```
<ul id="homepage-posts-block" class="tabs-search quicktabs-tabs quicktabs-style-nostyle"> 
    <li class="grid-feat-ad-style active" onclick="zeigeFilter(catF, typF, locF)"><a class="current" href="#"></i><?php _e( 'Categories', 'agrg' ); ?></a></li>
    <li class="list-feat-ad-style" onclick="zeigeFilter(locF, typF, catF)" ><a class="" href="#"></i><?php _e( 'Types', 'agrg' ); ?></a></li>
    <li class="list-feat-ad-style" onclick="zeigeFilter(typF, catF, locF)" ><a class="" href="#"></i><?php _e( 'Locations', 'agrg' ); ?></a></li>
</ul>
```

After selecting one, the function "zeigeFilter" is called:

```
<script>
function zeigeFilter(var id1,var id2,var id3 ) {
    document.getElementById(id1).style.visibility = 'show';
    document.getElementById(id2).style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById(id3).style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
</script>
```

Depending on which Option is selected the specific  shell be displayed.

```
<ul class="filters-lists" id="catF">
  <li>..</li>
</ul>
<ul class="filters-lists" id="typF">
  <li>..</li>
</ul>
<ul class="filters-lists" id="locF">
  <li>..</li>
</ul>
```

My Problem is, that all three lists are shown at any time. I hope someone can help me.

Thanks,
joh

Answer (score 0):

Here comes the solution :

- it is not 'show' but 'visible' for the visibility property (CSS)
- wrong paramters for the call of 'zeigeFilter' method

The correct code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function zeigeFilter(id1, id2, id3) {
    document.getElementById(id1).style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById(id2).style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById(id3).style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
</script>

<ul id="homepage-posts-block" class="tabs-search quicktabs-tabs quicktabs-style-nostyle"> 
    <li class="grid-feat-ad-style active" onclick="zeigeFilter('catF', 'typF', 'locF')"><a  class="current" href="#"></i>premier</a></li>
    <li class="list-feat-ad-style" onclick="zeigeFilter('typF', 'catF', 'locF')"><a class="" href="#"></i>deuxieme</a></li>
    <li class="list-feat-ad-style" onclick="zeigeFilter('locF', 'typF', 'catF')" ><a class="" href="#"></i>troiseme</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="filters-lists" id="catF">
  <li>..</li>
</ul>
<ul class="filters-lists" id="typF">
  <li>..</li>
</ul>
<ul class="filters-lists" id="locF">
  <li>..</li>
</ul>
```